# Eclipse not responding on Windows 7 for Android Development

Tags: windows, eclipse, android

I am having a lot of problem getting Eclipse with Android plug-in to work on Windows 7 64K.  I am getting eclipse not responding a lot. It seem to happen pretty randomly. I know that Windows 7 is currently not support for Android SDK.

However has anyone got this to work ?

I am using the following:
- Windows 7 64K 
- eclipse galileo (3.5.2)
- JDK 1.6.0_21 64k

Answer (score 5):

There are probably several problems here with the same "not responding" symptoms. SO the following might not work for everybody.

I am running Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with Eclipse Helios Service Release 1, and see the Eclipse "not responding" quite frequently (every day or so). So far I can usually fix it by stopping the adb.

- Go to the Windows Task Manger (CTRL-ALT-DEL then Start Task Manager)
- In the Processes tab sort the Image Name column
- Select adb.exe *32
- End Process
- End Process on the check dialog as well.

You may see console warnings about "DeviceMonitor]Connection attempts" but Eclipse should now be unblocked and will restart adb after a short while.

Comment: I still (in 2013) encountered the problem from time to time, this is was helped...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed.  This is due to a bug in JDK 1.6.0_21 build 6.  The problem is fixed in build 7.   Here are related links....

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171988&start=0&

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

I've been seeing this a lot, so With jvisualvm, I triggered a thread dump, and I find a deadlock. This won't be cured by killing adb. I've reported it (and referenced this question): http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25149

```
Found one Java-level deadlock:
=============================
"Device Client Monitor":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0000000010516468 (object 0x00000000e14ca208, a java.util.ArrayList),
  which is held by "Device List Monitor"
"Device List Monitor":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0000000010516510 (object 0x00000000e9354218, a com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory),
  which is held by "main"
"main":
  waiting to lock monitor 0x0000000010e01a98 (object 0x00000000e0dbd3f8, a java.util.ArrayList),
  which is held by "Device List Monitor"

Java stack information for the threads listed above:
===================================================
"Device Client Monitor":
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:657)
    - waiting to lock  (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:577)
"Device List Monitor":
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory.removeReceiverFor(LogCatReceiverFactory.java:53)
    - waiting to lock  (a com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory.access$000(LogCatReceiverFactory.java:31)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory$1.deviceDisconnected(LogCatReceiverFactory.java:41)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.deviceDisconnected(AndroidDebugBridge.java:797)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.updateDevices(DeviceMonitor.java:391)
    - locked  (a java.util.ArrayList)
    - locked  (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingDeviceData(DeviceMonitor.java:323)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:191)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$000(DeviceMonitor.java:42)
    at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$1.run(DeviceMonitor.java:82)
"main":
    at com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge.addClientChangeListener(AndroidDebugBridge.java:437)
    - waiting to lock  (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPidToNameMapper.(LogCatPidToNameMapper.java:46)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver.(LogCatReceiver.java:59)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory.newReceiver(LogCatReceiverFactory.java:62)
    - locked  (a com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.deviceSelected(LogCatPanel.java:243)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.SelectionDependentPanel.deviceSelected(SelectionDependentPanel.java:52)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.SelectionDependentViewPart.selectionChanged(SelectionDependentViewPart.java:67)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.DdmsPlugin$6.run(DdmsPlugin.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    - locked  (a org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

Found 1 deadlock.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 7 x64 and have been using it for Android Development. No problem whatsoever. Are you sure its the Android SDK, or is it the Android driver for your phone? Grab all the newest updates, and I put all my files and workspace outside of the users folder. This prevents any chance of permission issue.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I am definitely using the Android SDK. (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). And my workspace is outside user folder. What version of eclipse are you using ?

Comment: Version: 3.5.2 - Build id: M20100211-1343. Does it crash when you're using AVD? Or even without it?

Comment: Maybe its the Eclipse itself, can you list the plugins you have installed?

Comment: I only installed two plugins. 
- Android Dalvik Debug Monitor Service
- Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is probably hitting the garbage collector a lot. You can check if this is the cause by clicking `Show heap status` in Preferences | General.

You can try putting `-Xmx1024m` at the end of your `eclipse.ini` file. If there is already an `-Xmx` setting then replace it with that one. That will help keep the GC from pausing the UI so frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse helios 64bits on Windows 7 and it seems that the problem is back with the last JDK :
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

The workaround I used is to use the previous version of the JRE :
C:\eclipse-jee-helios-win32-x86_64\eclipse.exe -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java.exe"